# php form validation for my report creation not working

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, submit

I'm currently trying to valid my form to check for any empty fields as well as regular expressions but the thing is that the validation isn't working when I prompt it to activate. It worked well on the other page I had and I can't seem to find the issue.

PHP PAGE: CreateMonthlyFBForm (non working)

```
<?php
include "dbFunctions.php";
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    echo "You do not have access to this page.<br/>";
    echo "Please <a href='login.php'>login first</a>.";
    exit;
} elseif ($_SESSION['department'] == "CEP") {
    echo "Your account is not authorised to use the webpage.";
    echo "Please return to <a href='index.php'>index</a>";
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('.datepick').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var RE_REFNO = /^[0-9/]+$/;
            var RE_MTNNYR = /^[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}$/;
            var RE_SUBINS = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            function validate(form)
            {
                var refno = form.refno.value;
                var mthnyr = form.mthnyr.value;
                var subins = form.subins.value;
                //var date = form.date.value;
                //var time = form.time.value;
                //var RO = form.RO.value;
                //var Designation = form.Designation.value;
                //var Contact = form.Contact.value;
                //var priority = form.priority.value;
                //var no1 = form.no1.value;
                //var no2 = form.no2.value;
                //var no3 = form.no3.value;
                //var no4 = form.no4.value;
                //var no5 = form.no5.value;
                //var no6 = form.no6.value;
                //var no7 = form.no7.value;
                //var no8 = form.no8.value;
                //var fb1 = form.fb1.value;
                //var fb2 = form.fb2.value;
                //var fb3 = form.fb4.value;
                //var fb4 = form.fb4.value;
                //var fb5 = form.fb5.value;
                var errors = [];
                if (!RE_REFNO.test(refno))
                {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Reference number must not contain letters and symbols other than '/'.";
                }
                if (refno == "") {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Reference number cannot be blank.";
                }
                if (!RE_MTHNYR.test(mthnyr))
                {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Month and Year must be written in this format (MM/YYYY)";
                }
                if (mthnyr == "") {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Month and Year cannot be blank.";
                }
                if (!RE_SUBINS.test(subins))
                {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Submitting Insititude does not have any numbers or symbols. Please recheck and re-enter.";
                }
                if (subins == "") {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Submitting Insititude cannot be blank.";
                }
                if (errors.length > 0) {
                    //alert("something is wrong");  
                    var msg = "Report creation Invalid.";
                    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                        msg += "\n" + errors[i];
                    }
                    alert(msg);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <title>RP Incident & Crisis Management System | Create CEP Monthly Feedback Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.php"><h1>RP Incident & Crisis Management System</h1></a>
        <img src="images/header_rplogo.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" height="80" width="220"/>
        <hr>
        <?php if ($_SESSION['department'] == "BCM") { ?>
            <table border="1" width="75%" align="center">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td width="13%"><a href="index.php">Home</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="search.php">Search for reports</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="create.php">Create report</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="edit.php">Edit reports</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($_SESSION['department'] == "CEP") { ?>
            <table border="1" width="75%" align="center">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td width="13%"><a href="index.php">Home</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="search.php">Search for reports</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="create.php">Create report</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="edit.php">Edit reports</a></td>
                    <td width="13%"><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php } ?>
        <br>
        <h2>CEP MONTHLY FEEDBACK FORM</h2>
        <form method="post" action="doMonthlyFBForm.php" class="formLayout" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="refno" for="refno"><b>Reference Number:<br><i>(Institution/Submitting Department/Running Number)</i></b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="refno"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="mthnyr" for="mthnyr"><b>Month/Year:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="mthnyr"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>To:</label></td>
                    <td>HED, MOE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Email:</label></td>
                    <td><b>Gan_Beng_Tat@moe.gov.sg</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="subins" for="subins">Submitting Institution</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="subins"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="date" for="date">Date of report submission</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" class="datepick" id="datepicker1" name="date"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="time" for="time">Time of report submission</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="time"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Name" for="Name">Reporting Officer Name:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="RO"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Designation" for="Designation">Reporting Officer Designation:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="Designation"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Contact" for="Contact">Reporting Officer Contact No:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="Contact"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h3><u>Details of Specific Incident</h3></u></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Priority:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="priority" value="Immediate"/>Immediate
                        <input type="radio" name="priority" value="Urgent"/>Urgent
                        <input type="radio" name="priority" value="Routine"/>Routine (Please tick)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no1" for="no1">Nature of Incident:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="no1" rows="3" size ="20" cols="35" name="no1"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="date" for="date">Date of Incident:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" class="datepick" id="datepicker2" name="no2"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no2" for="no2">Time of Incident:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="no3"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no3" for="no3">Location of Incident:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="no3" rows="1" size ="20" cols="35" name="no4"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no4" for="no4">Particulars of Parties </br> Involved (if available):</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="no4" rows="1" size ="20" cols="35" name="no5"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no5" for="no5">Details of incident:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="no5" rows="5" size ="20" cols="35" name="no6"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no6" for="no6">Action taken:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="no6" rows="2" size ="20" cols="35" name="no7"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="no7" for="no7">Remarks: (e.g. any decision/support required from MHA, any problems encountered/challenges faced when taking action, any lessons learnt, etc)</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="no7" rows="5" size ="20" cols="35" name="no8"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h3><u>Feedback (if any)</h3></u></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fb1" for="fb1">Feedback:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="fb1" rows="3" size ="20" cols="35" name="fb1"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fb2" for="fb2">Feedback from?:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="fb2" rows="1" size ="20" cols="35" name="fb2"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fb3" for="fb3">Details of Feedback:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="fb3" rows="3" size ="20" cols="35" name="fb3"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fb4" for="fb4">Action taken:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="fb4" rows="3" size ="20" cols="35" name="fb4"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fb5" for="fb5">Remarks:</label></td>
                    <td><textarea id="fb5" rows="3" size ="20" cols="35" name="fb5"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Create Report" name="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's happening now is that I'm just trying to get it to check for the first 3 fields but everytime I click submit it just goes through to the next page.

PHP PAGE: Register (working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>RP Incident & Crisis Management System | Register</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var RE_NAME = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
            var RE_EMAIL = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;
            var RE_USERNAME = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            var RE_PASSWORD = /^[A-Za-z\d]{8,30}$/;
            function validate(form)
            {
                var name = form.name.value;
                var email = form.email.value;
                var username = form.username.value;
                var password = form.password.value;
                var confirmPassword = form.confirmPassword.value;
                var department = form.department.value;
                var errors = [];
                if (!RE_NAME.test(name))
                {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Name is invalid. It must not contain numbers and symbols.";
                }

                if (!RE_EMAIL.test(email))
                {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Email is invalid. Please check if you've mispelled your email or forgotten the '@' symbol.";
                }

                if (!RE_USERNAME.test(username))
                {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Username Invalid. Username must not contain symbols.";
                }

                if (department == "") {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Please select a department.";
                }

                if (password != confirmPassword) {
                    errors[errors.length] = "Passwords do not match.";
                    form.password.value = "";
                    form.confirmPassword.value = "";
                } else {
                    if (!RE_PASSWORD.test(password)) {
                        errors[errors.length] = "You must enter a valid password.";
                    }
                }
                if (errors.length > 0) {
                    //alert("something is wrong");
                    var msg = "Registration Invalid.";
                    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                        msg += "\n" + errors[i];
                    }
                    alert(msg);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.php"><h1>RP Incident & Crisis Management System</h1></a>
        <img src="images/header_rplogo.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" height="80" width="220"/>
        <hr>    
        <h2>REGISTER</h2>
        <form method="post" action="doRegister.php" class="formLayout" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Name:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="name"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Username:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="28" name="username"/></td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Password:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" size="28" name="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Confirm<br> Password:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" size="28" name="confirmPassword"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Email:</b></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="40" name="email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><b>Department:</b></label></td>
                    <td><select name="department">
                            <option value="">Select your department</option>
                            <option value="BCM">BCM Taskforce</option>
                            <option value="CEP">CEP Taskforce</option>
                            <option value="Flu">Flu Taskforce</option>
                            <option value="ECC">ECC</option>
                            <option value="CC">Crisis Comms</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="role" value="member"/>
            </table>
            <br>
            <a href="login.php"><i>Have an account?</i></a>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a working one. But I just can't seem to get the function to work on my other page.

Sorry, I'm still new and frankly pretty terrible to the whole coding thing and I'm just trying to pass my assignment to graduate and gtfo of this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your console you will see that you have an error occurring that breaks the code half way down which is caused by misspelling of your `RE_MTHNYR` variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RE_REFNO = /^[0-9/]+$/;
// Spelling of ---> RE_MTNNYR
// Should be -----> RE_MTHNYR
// Notice double "NN" instead of "HN"
var RE_MTNNYR = /^[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}$/;

var RE_SUBINS = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
function validate(form) {
    ...........etc.
    }
    // This is the name used here "RE_MTHNYR"
    if (!RE_MTHNYR.test(mthnyr)) {
```

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU ARE RIGHT. HOW COULD I BE SO CARELESS. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: and one silly question, where do I find the console?

Comment: The console is in your browser. I use Safari so it's under the "Develop" drop down. It should be in the same general place as a "View Source" option.

Comment: Also, not a silly question, I had no idea where this elusive "console" was either until one day, by chance, I discovered it in my browser.